# dispatching to react store outside of component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am having difficulty updating my store after calling an API. I am using reduxjs/toolkit. Here is the structure of the project:

```
react/
    store/
    api/
    dataconsumer/
        dataSlice.js
    notifications/
        notificationsSlice.js
    app.js
```

Here, `api` contains non-component API calls to the server. They are bound to `thunk` functions within `dataSlice` and a successful query updates data just fine.

The following are relevant parts to my reducers.

```
notificationSlice.js
const slice = createSlice({
    ..., 
    reducers: {
        // need to call this from api
        setNotifications: (state, action) => state.notification = action.payload
    }
})
```

```
dataSlice.js

export const fetchInitialData = createAsyncThunk(
    'chart/fetchInitialData',
    async (data) => {
        return API.candles.initialData({
            ...data
        })
    }

const slice = createSlice({
   ...
   extraReducers: {
      ...
      [fetchInitialData.success]: (state, action) => state.action = action.payload
}
})
```

And the api

```
const fetchInitialData = () => {
    return fetch(url, {
        ...
    }).then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data.status === 200) { return data } // works great!
        else {
            // doesn't work, but functionally what I'm looking for
            store.dispatch(setNotifications(data.status)) 
        }

     })
}
```

The problem is when the response is other than 200, I need to update notifications, but I don't know how to get the data to that reducer.

I can't `useDispatch` because it is outside a component, and if I import the `store` to my api files it is outside the `context provider` and my state is uninitialized.

I'm sure I could use `localStorage` to solve the problem or some other hack, but I feel I shouldn't have to and I'm wondering if there is a key principle I'm missing when organizing my react-redux project? or if there are standard solutions to this problem.

Thanks - I'm new to redux.

Comment: You can access the `thunkAPI` from the [createAsyncThunk - payload creator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator). Can you share your code?

Comment: I updated my question. I am successfully able to get data back to the dataSlice, since the api is associated with the `thunk function` defined in there. My question is how to get data to the `notificationSlice` if the response is not 200. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Would it not just be a `fetchInitialData.rehected` case reducer in the notification slice?

Comment: @drew How do I update `notifications` state from inside `dataconsumerSlice`? The `state` available inside `fetchInitialData.rejected` only allows access to `state.dataconsumer` and not `state.notifications` and I can't import any dispatch functions in my slice file. Again, I'm sure I"m missing something simple.

Comment: You don't... you update notifications state from the notifications slice. Reducers can handle any dispatched action. You add a reducer case to your notifications slice to handle the rejected promise of the `fetchInitialData` action.

Comment: @DrewReese Its working now. I would have thought it was bad practice to import and mix reducers like that (instead of just calling an update function) but fine with me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using thunk, then the best solution will be to use it in order to dispatch your action after you get the error.

You do it like this:

```
export const fetchInitialData = () => {
  return dispatch => {
...your logic
   else {
            // now you can dispatch like this
            dispatch(setNotifications(data.status)) 
        }
}
};
```

Comment: And what does `const fetchInitialData = createAsyncThunk( .....` do?